# ¿Cómo podría asignarle varios valores a una variable de php?

Tags: php

estoy intentando asignarle varios valores a una variable en php pero sin embargo me da error. Dejo el code y el error.

Code:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$latest_gads = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1 (compatible; AdsBot-Google-Mobile; +http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html)"."Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G920A) AppleWebKit (KHTML,\xC2\xA0like Gecko) Chrome Mobile Safari (compatible; AdsBot-Google-Mobile; +http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html)"."AdsBot-Google-Mobile-Apps";
if ($user_agent === "$latest_gads"){


    setcookie('Google', time()+31536000, '/');
    echo  <<<EOT
    <script>(function()
{
  if( window.localStorage )
  {
    if( !localStorage.getItem('firstLoad') )
    {
      localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
      window.location.reload();
    }  
    else
      localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
  }
})(); </script>
EOT;
}
```

ERROR:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pruba1\assets\php\vulnerer.php on line 9

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: Hola, en PHP no puedes asignar 2 o mas valores a una variable de la manera que lo estas intentando tendrás errores de sintaxis (escritura); la única forma de manjar varios valores es que la varia sea de tipo array o un json sring; podes aclarar que intentas hacer; tambien he notado que estas preguntando sobre conceptos básicos de programación estas en algún curso?

Comment: Hola @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent sii jeje, estoy empezando en php y en programación en general.
Te explico, lo que estoy intentando hacer es que mediante el condicional "if" verifique si existen varios user agents y en base a eso mostrar una página web adaptada a ese navegador, entonces se me ocurrió la idea de asignarle varios valores a una variables ya que me imagino que sobre usar el condicional if afectará al rendimiento de la página web. Te dejo el código completo de php en el siguiente comentario

Comment: $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$latest_gads = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1 (compatible; AdsBot-Google-Mobile; +http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html)"."Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G920A) AppleWebKit (KHTML,\xC2\xA0like Gecko) Chrome Mobile Safari (compatible; AdsBot-Google-Mobile; +http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html)"."AdsBot-Google-Mobile-Apps";
He probado la concatenación mediante "." tal y como dijo David, pero no ha funcionado

Comment: agrega el código a tu pregunta debes editarla... y ahora entiendo, pero me queda una nueva duda de donde obtines los diferentes user agent????

Comment: Los user agents de una web:
https://user-agents.net/bots/adsbot-google
Edito la pregunta ahora mismo

Comment: pero lo haces manual o estas consumiendo algún api???; deberías agregar la lista completa de user agent que vas a implementar.

Comment: De forma manual

Comment: y adonde vaz a redirigir al mismo url???

Comment: Sí, el plan es que se le asigne una cookie a través de su user agent, mediante esa cookie le aparecerán unos datos u otros conforme vaya explorando la web. He probado sin concatenaciones, y funciona, pero claro, ir uno por uno creo que afectará al rendimiento de la web

Comment: eso es lo que no me queda claro si tienes 10 user agent seran 10 cookies diferentes basado en que harás que sean diferentes... o mejor cual sera la diferencia

Comment: Claro, por eso me gustaría concatenarlos todo en un grupo, por ejemplo:
Google-Ads, en base a sus últimos user-agents haría un grupo con cookie llamada Google y así con las demás marcas, porque sino sería hacer:
Google_1: ua1
Google_2: ua2
etc, y a parte de ser lioso, pues debido a la gran cantidad de user agents creo que la página iría lenta a la hora de procesar las peticiones

Comment: entonces tambien requieres validar cual es la marca para que generar una cookies acorde; pero eso me deja una duda puedes ampliar la cantidad de user agent en tu post y que parámetro del user agent usarías pata diferenciar uno de otro????

Comment: Por el momento como estoy haciendo pruebas, únicamente estoy comprobando los user agents de google-ads.
Uso como parámetro el mismo user_agent, no uso parser.
Te explico mejor el procedimiento completo:
1. Un usuario o bot de google accede a la web, el código de php detecta que tiene un user agent, luego se le añade la cookie de Google.
2. Una vez que el sistema haya reconocido la cookie, recarga la web automáticamente para detectar la cookie y así mostrar el nuevo código

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130561/discussion-between-arcanis-the-omnipotent-and-galaixa-galicia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en las actualizaciones, comentarios y las aclaraciones lo que buscas es implementar una variable de tipo array y validar si existe un user-agent para luego redireccionar a la pagina especifica:

te muestro como se implementar el array y validar la existencia de un dato en el:

```php
$latest_gads = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1 (compatible; AdsBot-Google-Mobile; +http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html)",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G920A) AppleWebKit (KHTML,\xC2\xA0like Gecko) Chrome Mobile Safari (compatible; AdsBot-Google-Mobile; +http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html)",
    "AdsBot-Google-Mobile-Apps",
]; 

$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 


if (in_array($user_agent,$latest_gads)){
    echo "existe";
}else{
    echo "No existe";
}
```

estoy implementando variable de tipo [array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php) y el metodo [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) para evaluar la condición de si existe el user agent.